# Need more than 32 wireless mac filters

Tags: wireless-networking, mac-address, traffic-filtering

Are there any home or small business wireless routers that have more than 32 mac address filters? I'm currently using a Linksys WRT120N with a 32 address capacity and 32 is not enough.

Comment: Please provide more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: FWIW, MAC filters have been shown to be useless.  Anyone with a wireless sniffer and the desire can spoof an existing MAC addr.  A good password is much more secure

Comment: It is an odd situation. The goal is to limit access to certain devices so only certain people can use the internet -- but people can't be trusted not to share the password with people who shouldn't be using the internet. Protecting against MAC spoofing isn't that big of a deal in this use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linksys WRT54G(L) with DD_WRT will take 128 addresses.

Comment: This is a possibility -- ideally though just buying something that can support this with stock firmware is ideal.

Comment: I did a bit of research on this suggestion and it looks intriguing, but beyond my scope of knowledge and abilities. Thanks, though.

Comment: I finally got the nerve to give this a try and I LOVE it. DD_WRT solved my mac address problem and has proven to be much more stable. I have not had to reset my router since installation. Thank You!  -Charyl